# How do I get the login function to be able to access $scope.names

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, json

I am attempting to build a login page using AngularJS, php and javascript. I have a php page that contains JSON objects including usernames and password combinations. the data is accessed and stored in the $scope.names variable. what I want is for the login function to be able to access this array and determine whether the login information entered into the login form matches any combination found in the json file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<style>
table, th , td  {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  padding: 5px;
}
table tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
table tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
</style>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<body>

<button type = "button" class = "btn btn-primary" data-toggle = "modal" data-target = "#login">Log In</button>
<br/>
<br/>

<div class = "container">

    <h2>TTP Banking Portal</h2>
    <ul class = "nav nav-tabs">
        <li class = "active"><a data-toggle = "tab" href = "#home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle = "tab" href = "#transfer">Transfer Funds</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle = "tab" href = "#reports">Generate Reports</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle = "tab" href = "#chat">Chat with An Agent</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle = "tab" href = "#email">Email your Bank</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div class = "tab-content">

        <div id = "home" class = "tab-pane fade in active">



<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="clientsCtrl" id = "login" class = "modal fade">

        <div class = "modal-dialog">
            <div class = "modal-content">
                <div class = "modal-header">
                    <h3>Enter Login Information Below</h3>
                </div>
            <div class = "modal-body">
                <form>
                    <input type = "input" name = "user" placeholder = "Username" id = "Username" required>
                    <input type = "input" name = "pass" placeholder = "Password" id = "Password" required>
                    <button id = "loginbtn" type = "button" class = "btn btn-success" onclick = "login()">Log In</button>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class = "modal-footer">
                <button type = "button" class = "btn-warning" data-toggle = "modal" data-target = "#forgotPassword">Forget Password</button>
                <button type = "button" class = "btn btn-primary" id = "close" name = "close" data-dismiss = "modal">Close</button>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>


</div>

<script>

var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('clientsCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
        $http.get("clients.php")
        .then(function(response) {
            $scope.names = response.data.records;

        });
    });

function login() {
    var enteredUsername = document.getElementById("Username").value;
    var enteredPassword = document.getElementById("Password").value;
    console.log(enteredUsername + "," + enteredPassword);
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.names.length; i++) {
        console.log($scope.names[i]);
    }

}


</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Thank you.

Comment: Instead of returning the username/password combinations to the client, you  should check them on the server, preferably using an auth solution from a PHP framework. Anyone can see the json response from the server in the network tab of the devtools, making it very insecure.

Comment: the team i am working on, for some reason, wants to use this method. so, do you know how to do it this way?

Comment: $scope is a local variable. you cannot use that outside the controller. instead use a global variable called names and loop over it.

Comment: @PunithMithra that is true.  But instead of global variable, it makes a lot more sense to move the `login` function into the controller `$scope` and use `ng-click="login()"` instead of `onclick="login()"` and then you can also use `ng-model` for username and password instead of `document.getElementById` ... I see no advantage/reason why the login function should be outside of angular - doing it that way only will make life harder and you will miss the beauty of angular.

Comment: Yes @plong0, this is not the right way of angular js implementation.

Answer (score 1):

This is a pure implementation of the above code in AngularJS.

HTML: Defined model on input fields.

```
<form>
  <input ng-model='user.name' type="input" name="user" placeholder="Username" id = "Username" required>
  <input ng-model='user.password' type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Password" id="Password" required>
  <button id="loginbtn" type="button" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="login(user)">Log In</button>
 </form>
```

Script:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('clientsCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

  //this is sample data for names.
  $scope.names = [{username: 'abc', password: 'abc'},{username: 'abc1', password: 'abc1'}]; 
  $scope.user = {};
  $scope.login = function (user) {
    var enteredUsername = user.name,
        enteredPassword = user.password;
    console.log(enteredUsername + "," + enteredPassword);
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.names.length; i++) {
      if($scope.names[i].username === enteredUsername && $scope.names[i].password === enteredPassword) {
        alert('Logged In');
        break;
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this

1) Add login function in controller like

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('clientsCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
        $http.get("clients.php")
        .then(function(response) {
            $scope.names = response.data.records;

        });
$scope.Login= function(){
var enteredUsername = document.getElementById("Username").value;
    var enteredPassword = document.getElementById("Password").value;
    console.log(enteredUsername + "," + enteredPassword);
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.names.length; i++) {
        console.log($scope.names[i]);
    }
};
    });
```

Html code will become

```
 <form>
 <input type = "input" name = "user" placeholder = "Username" id = "Username" required>
 <input type = "input" name = "pass" placeholder = "Password" id = "Password" required>
<button id = "loginbtn" type = "button" class = "btn btn-success" ng-click = "Login()">Log In</button>
  </form>
```

2) Send `Names` as parameters to `Login` function

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('clientsCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
        $http.get("clients.php")
        .then(function(response) {
            $scope.names = response.data.records;

        });
    });

function login(Names) {
    var enteredUsername = document.getElementById("Username").value;
    var enteredPassword = document.getElementById("Password").value;
    console.log(enteredUsername + "," + enteredPassword);
    for (var i = 0; i < Names.length; i++) {
        console.log(Names[i]);
    }

}
```

Now Html code will be like

```
<form>
     <input type = "input" name = "user" placeholder = "Username" id = "Username" required>
     <input type = "input" name = "pass" placeholder = "Password" id = "Password" required>
    <button id = "loginbtn" type = "button" class = "btn btn-success" onclick = "login({{names}})">Log In</button>
      </form>
```

3) Use `Names` as global variable in script

```
<script>
var Names={}; //as Global scope can use anywhere in this script scope like I used in login function
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('clientsCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
        $http.get("clients.php")
        .then(function(response) {
            $scope.names = response.data.records;
            Names=response.data.records;

        });
    });

function login() {
    var enteredUsername = document.getElementById("Username").value;
    var enteredPassword = document.getElementById("Password").value;
    console.log(enteredUsername + "," + enteredPassword);
    for (var i = 0; i < Names.length; i++) {
        console.log(Names[i]);
    }

}


</script>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: when I change it to the first option, the click doesn't do anything. when i change it to the second option it says "names" is not defined.

Comment: the first option produces no error it is like the click never occurs, and i'm not sure how to use Names as a global variables

Comment: Be sure your `form` tag should be in controller scope () Edited to use `Names` as global scop

Comment: the form tag looks like this:

    <form ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="clientsCtrl">

Comment: Edited first option also, please try again.